# Bitmap memory management in Android OOM

Tags: android

Hello guys I have a app where I have to load images at any step which are inside asset folder,how to load them without making OOM exeption ?
I saw the other post,but didnt helped whats the practic to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Google has a rather excellent set of tutorials already made for loading images, which are located [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Alternatively, you could use a library that already does the work for you, like [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: Its cool but how can I load 10 images at once not one by one ?

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd create 10 AsyncTasks and do the processing in there so that they all load in parallel. You may need to use the `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` call.